# Which driver has the most wins at a specific venue?

Tags: formula-1

Lewis Hamilton has 8 victories at the British GP. Is there any driver that has more than 8 victories at a specific venue?

Comment: Do you care about most wins at one "named" GP or most wins at one venue? While all Hamilton's wins have been at Silverstone, the British GP has not always been at Silverstone.

Answer (score 2):

No, 8 is the most. Other venues where 8 was achieved are [Schumacher at the French GP and Hamilton at the Hungarian GP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Formula_One_driver_records#Most_wins_at_the_same_Grand_Prix).